# ile and into Jupiter notebook and I get error UTF-8

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, utf-8, jupyter-notebook

[image]

NameError: name 'pd' is not defined

Comment: can you post some more details? thanks!

Comment: Please provide more details. Post some relevant code.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you are trying to read a dictionary that is still in json format. Remember to use json.loads() before trying to read them. Try something like df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json.loads(json_data))

Comment: Use `import pandas as pd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UTF-8 is the default encoding but can't decode some positions in this dataset.
Try this:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv('File_name', encoding='latin')
```

Related information here: http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python3/text_file_processing.html

Comment: Thanks this worked, I also had to do conda update conda &
conda update conda-build